# Convergence of random variables of Beta distribution

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, random-variables

I have to find the Convergence of random variables. The random varialble $X_{n} \sim \beta_{I}(3,n), n=1,2,...$. Find the Convergence of random variables of $Z_{n}=nX_{n}, n=1,2,...$.
I tried to do it with Lévy's continuity theorem but I can't calculate the characteristic function. I did also the distribualnt but also couldn't calculate it. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Intuitively the mean and variance will both tend to $3$ and the limit density shape will look something like a Gamma distribution. [Wikipedia confirms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Special_and_limiting_cases) that the solution is indeed a Gamma distribution with shape $3$ (and rate or scale $1$)

Comment: For every $z>0$ and every $n\geqslant z$, $$P(Z_n\leqslant z)=P(X_n\leqslant z/n)=B(3,n)\int_0^{z/n}t^2(1-t)^{n-1}dt=\frac{B(3,n)}{n^3}\int_0^{z}u^2(1-u/n)^{n-1}du\to\cdots$$